# Using application encryption instead of relying on HTTPS

Tags: tls, mobile, certificate-pinning

I use Google Firebase Services. I am thinking about using only https on mobile to send and receive a payload from my server. I will have RSA encryption with a public key on all clients. So when a client wants to call my server, it'll only get encrypted data. But if the client calls my server to get data, it will be first authenticated as a real client using Google's auth token, then I send the client their unencrypted data via https endpoint that they called.

Possible issues:

Man in the middle attack.
I feel like this type of attack is only used to snoop data. Thus my encryption should prevent any important data from being leaked. Sending data back from using only the default https encryption should be relatively safe?

Client hacking the app:
I don't think this is a possibility but even if they do, they still won't get very far because I have a auth verification and only the rsa public key, along with my API endpoints. If its a game, I do validations in the backend. If it's just a social media app, they won't be able to get any user data that they are not supposed to due to Google's auth token verification.

Does this sound like a good enough security to skip SSL pinning? Because if the hacker can do all of the above, the SSL pinning can just be turned off in most android and jailbroken devices.

Comment: I am not clear about what you want to accomplish or what you want to protect and what you want to protect that from.

Comment: Idk maybe I am having security anxiety. Basically, I want my mobile app which is a dating app, to have security because users input important personal data. SSL pinning can be turned off in jailbroken iOS devices so I will encrypt by hardcoding a RSA public key on client and rsa private key on server. I want to protect user data and data integrity.

Comment: But hold on: who cares about pinning being turned off? In order for that to be an issue, an attacker would have to compromise the phone ***and*** set up a MITM attack. If the user's have circumvented their ***own*** client security, then the liabilities are up to them.

Comment: Okay you're right the user would have to put themselves in a pretty dumb situation to be snooped. So I guess my client side encryption is enough. What if the user is the attacker trying to lets say, get extra super-likes ? Assuming just using the app there is no way they can do this. But they can reverse engineer the app and expose all the API endpoints. I have google auth token to verify user. But my API endpoints will be exposed and so will my rsa public key, but its public so its ok. idk maybe im paranoid but would you be able to hack/ abuse the app set up like mine?

Comment: Here's your most important tip: anything you give the user is public. Code, keys, tokens, etc. You only want to protect the client info from going to other clients. If your *system* security depends on the clients secrets remaining secret, then you have bad design. Nothing you should have in the client should impact any other client if known.

Comment: ok thanks. So as far as I know nothing will compromise other clients security. My rsa keypair is 1024 and my API endpoint all require google auth verification so even if they dump binary get get all strings it's still useless. thanks. One last question, if client request data from server via HTTPs and I send my unencrypted data, but https itself encrypts it, it is safe right? Only when client send data I encrypt using public key but the response is not encrypted with public key, its only encrypted using https protocol.

Comment: *"Man in the middle attack.... Client hacking the app"* - you basically downplay the attack vectors which neither your method nor SSL pinning can prevent, assuming that the client can disable pinning or extract your RSA key. I don't see any actual security advantage your method provides over HTTPS with SSL pinning. And you don't actually claim any advantages, apart from stating that SSL pinning can be more easily turned off.

Comment: what do i do to secure mobile app?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i am just a college student making a social dating app i don't want to let my users down =( help.

Comment: @darrenzou: *"i am just a college student making a social dating app i don't want to let my users down"* - unfortunately this is not a useful problem description. Again, I don't see what you are doing better than SSL pinning and I don't see why SSL pinning is not sufficient in your case. Unfortunately you don't actually describe what threats you want to protect from, only how you want to protect.

Comment: "good enough security" - it is opinion based. Please be more specific.